# How to bind command click of MenuContextItem from one User Control to Other in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my code I have following User Controls

1. MyListUserControl
2. MyListItemUserControl

MyListUserControl loads list with items loaded from MyListItemUserControl,

on MyListItemUserControl I have a button on click of that I'm showing ContextMenu with multiple options.

Now on click of that MenuItem I have to call method from MyListUserControl, is it possible to do that?

In short following is the structure that I have

```
  MyListUserControl -> MyListItemUserControl -> ContextMenu Item Click -> Command from MyListUserControl
```

If I write ListItem code in same ListUserControl its working fine. But I would prefer the item and list code in separate classes.

**MyListUserControl xaml Code**

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                       <local1:MyListItemUserControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                           CommentData="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

I have DelegateCommand Defined in this class, which I would like to call from MyListItemUserControl

**MyListItemUserControl xaml**

```
<ContextMenu>
     <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Path=Data.MenuItem_Clicked}"
                            Header="{x:Static propertyRes:Resources.Txt_Copy}"
                            Style="{StaticResource menuItems}" />
     <MenuItem Header="{x:Static propertyRes:Resources.Txt_Edit}" Style="{StaticResource menuItems}" />
     <MenuItem Header="{x:Static propertyRes:Resources.Txt_Delete}" Style="{StaticResource menuItems}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Please post the markup for the `ContextMenu`.

Comment: You have marked this MVVM, but I see no mention of ViewModels. The ViewModel should be the glue between controls.

Comment: @mm8 please check I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

this is pseudo code, but should be enough for you to get the idea

```
<MyListItemUserControl>
    <MyListItemUserControl.ItemTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenuItem 
                    Header="Do stuff"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=DetailsView, Path=DataContext.DoStuffCommand" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Grid.ContextMenu>
            <!-- your content -->
        </Grid>
    </<MyListItemUserControl.ItemTemplate>
</MyListItemUserControl>

<MyListItemUserControl x:Name="DetailsView">
<!-- I assume that data context is MyListItemViewModel or something similar
   it has the command: DataContext.DoStuff that takes items from list as parameter -->
</MyListItemUserControl>
```

EDIT:

If your controls are defined in seperate files you just need to pass the commnad. I usually do this by adding a dependency property in code behind that holds the command:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DoStuffCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DoStuffCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

        public ICommand DoStuffCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand) GetValue(DoStuffCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DoStuffCommandProperty, value); }
        }
```

so you can do:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                       <local1:MyListItemUserControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                           CommentData="{Binding}" DoStuffCommand="{Binding DoStuffCommandInSomeViewModel}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you please check code that I have added for question, basically I need to bind DelegateCommand of UserControl which contains actual list from the other ListItem User Control, both user controls are separate

Comment: thanks again, I started doing changes, now I'm stuck on what to write in Context Menu command.